# JSF unable to process onload method

Tags: jsf, viewaction

I have a jsf page. I want to reload the page everytime an it is refreshed

I tried this code but it was not working

```
  public String onload() { 

    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    String id = viewRoot.getViewId();

    if(previousPage!=null && previousPage.equals(id)){

    return "brcmBuildSheet?faces-redirect=true";  
    }

    previousPage = id;

    return "";
}
```

So I decided to use numbers to indicate whether it has been loaded.

```
     public String onload() { 

    if (previousViewID !=nextViewID ){  
        nextViewID=0;
         System.out.println("reload");

    return "brcmBuildSheet?faces-redirect=true";  //brcmBuildSheet?faces-redirect=true

    }

      ++nextViewID;
      System.out.println("first page");
    return "First page, but increment value for reload";

}
```

This is my jsf page

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
<f:viewAction action="#{buildsheetController.onload}" /> 
</f:metadata>
```

I got this error

```
JSF1095: The response was already committed by the time we tried to set the outgoing cookie for the flash.  Any values stored to the flash will not be available on the next request.
```

Update: When I set the second return value to null, it gives me this error

```
2018-07-30T14:57:52.975+0800|Severe: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.
```

Comment: A couple of things, 1: your title is sort of unclear. 'onload' is your method name, effectively, you have a problem with a viewAction. 2: Returning either `"brcmBuildSheet?faces-redirect=true""` or `"First page, but increment value for reload"` is weird. 3: There is nothing PrimeFaces or eclipse related in this question and java-ee is way to broad.  4: _" I want to reload the page everytime an it is refreshed"_ is unclear to me. You mean you don't want it to be cached?

Comment: Whenever I perform the search function, my results stay the same everytime after I refresh the table. I want to retrieve a brand new buildsheetList again each time I refresh the page. I found out my problem, I realize it's due to the return value.

Answer (score -1):

I found out the problem to my codes. My second return is not supposed to be an empty statement or irrelevant strings. In order to return values for the first "if" statement but not the "else" statement, I moved the return part to a whole new method. I also remove the return statement from the onLoad method.

```
  public void onload() {

    if (reload) {
        System.out.println("reload");
        reload = false;
        refresh();
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("first page");
        buildsheetList = getBuildsheetService().getAllBuildsheet();
        batch = null;
        title = null;
        misc = null;

      }
    }


public String refresh() {
    return "brcmBuildSheet?faces-redirect=true"; // brcmBuildSheet?faces-redirect=true

}
```

Comment: This is not working as you think it is. The onload is never going to return anything (since the return method is void). If you just remove the refresh, it will behave identical...